# easiest way to map ids during database refactoring

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, refactoring

i have a number of tables with a column called **OrderId**.  I have just done a refactoring and i want to get rid of the **Order** table and i have a new table called **Transaction**.  I want all tables that have an **OrderId** column to now have a **TransactionId** column

This is complete.   I now need to populate the **transactionId** column.  I have a mapping today between **orderId** and **transactionId**  so i wanted to see the quickest way i can go populate that new **transactionId**  column  (should i do this through code, through a SQL query, etc ??)

So i have the transationId column in the Order Table so i can do a join.

I want a query that says something like this (pseudo SQL)

```
update childTable CT
set transactionId = MapFromOrderId(CT.OrderId)
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in SQL code:

```
UPDATE MT
SET
    transaction_id = MAP.transaction_id
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN My_Map MAP ON
    MAP.order_id = MT.order_id
```

Then check to make sure that every row was mapped:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    My_Table
WHERE
    transaction_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The process is usually:

- Make sure the database is backed up
- Addtransctionid to each child table.
  Populate based on a join to the
  mapping table (you did store the
  mappings between orderid and
  transactionid in a table?)
- Make sure you have no blank values.
- Then you create the FK for
  transactions, drop the fk to the
  Order table and then drop the orderid
  column.
- Then move to the next table and
  repeat.
- Test to make sure everything worked
  properly

Definitely I'd do this in a script so it will be easy to port to prod after dev and QA testing.

On prod you need to do this while the database is in single user mode to prevent new orders from being added as the process transitions.

Comment: yes, i do that the mapping from orderId to transactionId in the Order Table.  i added some more information to the question to get at the heart of what i am looking for . . .